# How can handle JInternalFrame Close opeartion from JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I have one `JFrame(HMSDoctor)` and in that i am calling one `JInternalFrame(CurrentOPD)` by using `JDesktopPane`.

```
//opening JInternalFrame(CurrentOPD) by using JDesktopPane in JFrame(HMSDoctor).

       JDesktopPane jdp=new JDesktopPane();
   jdp.add(new CurrentOPD);

//Above code display proper JInternalFrame.
```

When i close that JInternalFrame at that time i want to execute one other JInternalFrame(Follow) in `JFrame(HMSDoctor)`.

How can i do like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, First you have to `addInternalFramaeListener` in main `frame` and when your `JInternalFrame(CurrentOPD)` closed at that time you can call `JInternalFrame(Follow)`

Answer (score 5):

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an Internal Frame Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/internalframelistener.html). I would guess you would want to listen for the "closed" event and then do some additional processing.

Comment: @DaxeshPrajapati, seriously, you unaccepted this answer for the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (SHOW.equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        ...
        if (listenedToWindow == null) {
            listenedToWindow = new JInternalFrame("Event Generator",
                                                  true,  //resizable
                                                  true,  //closable
                                                  true,  //maximizable
                                                  true); //iconifiable
            //We want to reuse the internal frame, so we need to
            //make it hide (instead of being disposed of, which is
            //the default) when the user closes it.
            listenedToWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                                    WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

            listenedToWindow.addInternalFrameListener(this);
            ...
        }
    } 
    ...
}
```